# How to pass an argument to a docker container using airflow's DockerOperator

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I have a docker image that runs a python script.

The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD . /


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3.6", "./main.py"]
```

As I understand it, using ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD to run the python script allows parameters to be passed to main.py that can be parsed with argparse within main.py

I have succesfully passed in arguments and retrieved and used them in main.py when running the docker container (named param-test) with the following command:

```
docker run -it param-test "cats"
```

I now wish to do the equivalent of the above 'docker run' command via Apache Airflow.

I have the following code that creates a DockerOperator within airflow succesfully but i am unclear how to pass the argument in this code configuration like i do in the above docker run command:

```
DockerOperator(dag=dag,
            task_id='my_task_name',
            image='my_docker_container_ecr_url'
)
```

How do i pass the param "cats" to the DockerOperator in an equivalent way to running:

```
docker run -it param-test "cats"
```

so that my python script cat use the cats param?

EDIT:
python code in main.py that uses the cats param passed in from docker:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('city')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.cat_var)
```

Comment: If want to use the arguments in Python you have to get them from `sys.argv`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Using the above docker run command I can use the arguments in my python script using argparse

Comment: @KlausD. I have added the code from main.py showing how i succesfully use argparse to use the input var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work

```py
DockerOperator(dag=dag,
            task_id='my_task_name',
            image='my_docker_container_ecr_url',
            command='cats'
)
```